# Move folder name to #,[A-Z]

Tags: batch-file

I want to sort the letters folders name move to folders #,[A-Z]

Thanks for the help.

Example.

Folders Name:

```
10 Cloverfield Lane (2016) ---> move to folder #
12 Rounds (2009) ---> move to folder #
12 Rounds 2 Reloaded (2013) ---> move to folder #
12 Rounds 3 Lockdown (2015) ---> move to folder #
12 Strong (2018) ---> move to folder #
13 Hours The Secret Soldiers of Benghazi (2016) ---> move to folder #
2 Fast 2 Furious (2003) ---> move to folder #
2012 (2009) ---> move to folder #

A Good Day to Die Hard (2013) ---> move to folder A
A Man Apart (2003) ---> move to folder A
A Million Ways to Die in the West (2014) ---> move to folder A
A Quiet Place (2018) ---> move to folder A
A View to a Kill (1985 ---> move to folder A
A-X-L (2018) ---> move to folder A
ATM Er Rak Error (2012) ---> move to folder A

Bad Boys (1995) ---> move to folder B
Bad Boys II (2003) ---> move to folder B
Bad Moms (2016) ---> move to folder B
```

Comment: Good luck with achieving your result. If you have written your code and you however get stuck, you're welcome to post it here so we can try and assist you with it.

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `for /?` and read the output help. Then run `if /?` and `md /?` and read output help and and last run `move /?` and read the output help. `for %%I in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) do if exist "%%I*" md "C:\Temp\#" 2>nul & move "%%I*" "C:\Temp\#\"` and `for %%I in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do if exist "%%I*" md "C:\Temp\%%I" 2>nul & move "%%I*" "C:\Temp\%%I\"`. The destination folders should not be in directory containing the files to move on using these two command lines. You see your question is too broad.

Comment: And the batch file should not be in directory of the files to move or its file name starts for example with `_` as otherwise the batch file would be also moved while `cmd.exe` is processing it resulting in task perhaps not done completely.

Comment: There's a feature called drag-and-drop in Windows Explorer which you could make use of...

Answer (score 0):

scipt don't move directory i need move directory.

```
for %%I in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) do if exist "%%I*" md "D:\test\#" 2>nul & move "%%I*" "D:\test\#\"
```

and

```
for %%I in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do if exist "%%I*" md "D:\test\%%I" 2>nul & move "%%I*" "D:\test\%%I"
```